# Hiding a TR with ajax/js

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following HTML:

```
   <tr id="n16">
    <td class="t_row">Text <a href="#" onClick="javascript:notification_dismiss('16');">Dismiss</a></td>
   </tr>
```

I want to update my database and hide the TR when people click Dismiss. Updating the database is working fine, but the TR won't hide. I have this JS:

```
function stateChanged(str)
{
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
 {
 document.getElementById("n" & str).display = 'none'
 }
}
```

I need to dynamically pass the TR's ID to the JS (using the "str" variable), but that part doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the binary `&` operator for string concatenation.  You need to use `+`.

```
document.getElementById("n" & str).display = 'none';
//                          ↑ change this character to `+`
```